# createrawtransaction for stuck transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have stuck transaction more than a week with 1 sat/vbyte?
How I can use **`createrawtransaction`** with only one input same as stuck transaction. It will pay the fees.

Comment: What specific issue are you having with `createrawtransaction`? It would be helpful if you can provide a specific example, what you've tried, and where you are having an issue. You can also check `bitcoin-cli help createrawtransaction` for examples on how to get started

Answer (score 0):

I deleted mempool.dat and did CPFP for stuck transaction after restarting core and it's worked,thanks to '/dev/fd0'